# Close Case If No Reply Within 48 Hours?

Tags: trigger, workflow, email2case

How can I handle if customer doesn't reply within 48 hours of email sent to him and close the case automatically?

Comment: for a particular case status.For example status is 'Waiting for Reply'

Comment: Please do not add detail as comments, but rather **[edit]** your post for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using nothing but configuration via the Process Builder.

## Step 1: Create Timer Field

On the Case object, create a date time field with no default value.

## Step 2: Create Process 1

In Process Builder, on the Email Message object, when the message is outgoing, update the parent case's Status to Waiting on Customer, and the Date Time field to the current time. If you're using Email-to-Case, you can also change the Status back to Working when an incoming message comes back from the customer.

## Step 3: Create Process 2

In the Process Builder, on the Case object, when the Status is Waiting on Customer, set a delayed trigger for 48 hours after the date/time field from the first step, then set the Status to Closed.

---

Alternative:

You can do the same thing with regular Workflow Rules as well, the design would be nearly identical. Finally, if you really wanted to do it with code, you'd need a scheduled class that runs hourly to find cases to close. I'd recommend avoiding this path if you can help it.